# Why am I getting a segmentation fault here? [C]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is going to get negative votes but I don't even care as long as someone can help me out. I have no access to a debugger and I could have finished hours ago if I did.

Why am I getting a segmentation fault here? Doesn't that mean that I am trying to access some memory location that does not belong to my process? Should I implement a buffer before copying data from one file to the next (though I don't know why it would matter)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int error( char * msg )
{
    perror( msg );
    return 2;
}

int usage( char * name )
{
    printf( "Usage: %s <file to copy> <name of copy>\n", name );
    return 1;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    //making sure all required arguments have been passed
    if ( argc != 3 )
        return usage( argv[0] );

    //Make sure input exists, make sure output does not exist
    char *inputFname = argv[1];
    char *outputFname = argv[2];
    FILE *inputFile;
    FILE *outputFile;
    inputFile = fopen(inputFname, "r");
    int err = errno;
    outputFile = fopen(outputFname, "r");

    //handle file opening errors
    if(outputFile != NULL){
        return error("Error: target file already exists\n");
        fclose(outputFile);
    }
    if(inputFile == NULL && err == 2){
        //errno of 2 corresponds to error code ENOENT; no such file or directory
        return error("Error: file does not exist\n");
        fclose(inputFile);
    }
    if(inputFile == NULL && err ==  19){
        //errno of 19 corresponds to error code EACCE; permission error
        return error("Error: permission denied for file\n");
        fclose(inputFile);
    }
    fclose(outputFile);

    //no errors upon opening, gather info and make buffer
    printf("No errors, proceeding with copy");
    struct stat info;
    stat(inputFname, &info);

    //create new file
    outputFile = fopen(outputFname, "w");
    chmod(outputFname, info.st_mode & 07777);

    //copy the contents
    char nextChar;
    while( (nextChar = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF)
        fputc(nextChar, outputFile);

    printf("copy completed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `char nextChar;` to `int nextChar;`.

Comment: `//no errors upon opening` Given the posted code, this comment should rather be `//no errors 2 or 19 upon opening, other errors not checked`. The `inputFile` is not guaranteed to be `!= NULL` by the time it's used. As a side note `fclose` _after_ `return` never does anything useful.

Comment: @RSahu No that's not it, that part is fine, I actually just figured it out. Thank you for taking the time thought

Comment: @dxiv That `fclose` was the very problem. I got rid of it and it solved it. I thought it just closed the currently opened file, but it gets ride of the `FILE` pointer. So when I tried to open a second file later on, the pointer was gone, and thus the segmentation fault

Comment: @jphollowed, you should make that change regardless. Otherwise, you will run into problems if `char` is unsigned type on your platform.

Comment: @jphollowed Btw,  if, assuming `outputFile` is a file you are *writing* to, then shouldn't the flag for the line `outputFile = fopen(outputFname, "r");` be "w" instead of "r"? And `if(outputFile != NULL)` should be `if(outputFile == NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fclose(outputFile);`
   Here lies the error. What if `outputFile` is NULL? i.e. target file doesn't already exist (desirable condition)?

   `man -s3 fclose`:

   > The behavior of fclose() is undefined if the stream parameter is  an illegal  pointer.

---

2. And after returning from `main` how do you think `fclose` gonna work?

   `return error("Error: target file already exists\n");`
   `fclose(outputFile);`

---

3. What if `inputFile` is `NULL` and `errno` is neither `2` nor `19`?

   Hint: In that case previous two `if`s will not exit `main` and the program will continue well past file error checking code with `inputFile = NULL`.

---

4. Also you didn't closed the streams ones the copy completed.

---

I think the best way to write this code is to check for inputFile's error immediately after opening the input file. if `NULL` then exit else go on.

Then similarly check for output file. if *NOT* `NULL` then exit else go on.

So the correct code snippet would be:

```
...
inputFile = fopen(inputFname, "r");
int err = errno;

if(inputFile == NULL)
{ 
    if (err == 2)
        return error("Error: file does not exist\n");

    if(err ==  19)
        return error("Error: permission denied for file\n");

    return error("Other Error");
}

outputFile = fopen(outputFname, "r");
if(outputFile != NULL)
{
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);
    return error("Error: target file already exists\n");
}  
...  
printf("copy completed");  
fclose(inputFile);
fclose(outputFile);
return 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

I could, and probably should, just delete this low-quality question, but I figured it out and am going to answer my own question since it seems like people ask this exact same thing quite often; perhaps this will be of some help.

The problem was when I called `fclose()` after checking for errors. I thought that I was closing the most recently opened *file*, `outputFile`. But I was actually completely getting rid of the `FILE` pointer, `*outputFile`. So, later on, when I tried to open another file to the same `FILE` pointer, the pointer was gone, hence the segmentation fault. That's what I get for thinking in object-oriented ways!

Comment: This looks confused to me. "[C]ompletely getting rid of the FILE pointer"? The pointer variable `f` (and even the pointer value that it contains!) is still there after calling `fclose(f)`. It's just that the open stream is closed. There is no problem doing `f = fopen("someotherfile.txt", "w");` afterwards.

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood what the issue was (or maybe still is). `fclose(outputFile)` does indeed *close* `outputFile` - and that's not the `most recently opened file` but the FILE pointer `outputFile` that you explicitly pass to `fclose`. As for the `when I tried to open another file to the same FILE pointer, the pointer was gone, hence the segmentation fault` this makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @divx: I'm starting to think that when he writes "file pointer" he doesn't mean the pointer variable, but the `FILE` data object that it points to. But I still don't understand what he means.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy This leaves both of us guessing.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy That is what I think I meant, but I didn't think the term "object" was correct for lower level languages. Beside that, what i described above was the issue, and the code works now, even if I don't know what the heck I'm talking about.

Comment: @jphollowed: I still don't understand what you are saying. Are you saying that once you have done `fclose(f);`, you can't do `f = fopen("someotherfile.txt", "w");`? Or that once you have done `fclose(f);`, you can't do `fclose(f);` again?